How to derive the expression for number of teeth in virtual spur gears
Several literary sources express the number of teeth of a virtual gear by the following equation
$$
z_v = \frac{z}{\cos^3 \beta} \tag{1}
$$
where the derivation is based on the radius of osculating circle for ellipse in virtual gears through the referencing diameter on the real spur helical gear
$$
r_v = \frac{r}{\cos^2 \beta} \Longrightarrow \not m_n z_v = \frac{m_t z}{\cos^2 \beta} = \frac{\not m_n}{\cos \beta} \frac{z}{\cos^2 \beta} \tag{2}
$$
On the other end, for instance in ISO standards the virtual number of teeth is expressed as:
$$
z_v = \frac{z}{\cos^2 \beta_b \cos \beta} \tag{3}
$$
where the angle $\beta_b$ is the helix angle $\beta$ on the base circle, which is defined as:
$$
\sin \beta_b = \sin \beta \cos \alpha_n \tag{4}
$$
Since the equation (3) is incorporated in different gear calculation programs and in some standards as well, the correct expression should be the forementioned equation (3). Thus the equation (1) can be considered as an approximation, because of the neglectable difference between $\beta_b$ and $\beta$.
My question is: How can the equation (3) be derived?
